# Show that $e^A e^B=e^{A+B} e^{[A,B]/2}$?

Tags: matrices

How to show that $$e^A e^B=e^{A+B}e^{[A,B]/2}$$

where $A$ and $B$ are matrices and $[A,B]=AB-BA$

My attempt was to write a function:

$F(t)=e^{tA}e^{tB}$ and then to differentiate it as follows:

$F'(t)=Ae^{tA}e^{tB}+e^{tA}Be^{tB}$

From this, it is clear that if $A$ and $B$ commute then after solving the above differential equation the function gives the correct answer if commutator is zero but how to derive the explicit form as asked in the question?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula

Comment: In other words, your formula is incorrect in general.  It will be OK provided all commutators of 3 or more (like $[A,[B,A]]$ and so on) are zero.

Comment: @Lost I suspect that you have forgotten to mention an assumption here. [This section of the BCH wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula#Special_cases) mentions that your formula holds under the assumption that $[A,[A,B]] = [B,[A,B]] = 0$, but does not mention a more general equality.

Comment: see as well: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3390076

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the assumption.